# Finding a child member that is a QPointer

Tags: c++, qt, qpointer

I am trying to use `findChildren` to pull a list of parameters from my program.  The code is below:

```
QList<QPointer<TParameter> > theFullParameterList;

foreach(TParameter *child, this->findChildren<TParameter* >())
{
    theFullParameterList << QPointer<TParameter>(child);
}
```

It compiles fine but but When I go into (this) within debug, there are several member types of `QPointer<TParameter>` but my `theFullParameterList` comes up empty.  `TParameter` is a custom class. Is there any way to find the children of that class that are within a `QPointer`?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions:

1) Are you sure that such instances of that class is not destroyed when you call `findChildren`?

2) Are you sure to set the parent to the class instances?

I'm able to populate the `QList` with the following code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        new TParameter(this);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QList<QPointer<TParameter>> theFullParameterList;

    foreach(TParameter *child, findChildren<TParameter*>())
        theFullParameterList << QPointer<TParameter>(child);

    qDebug() << "Size of list:" << theFullParameterList.size();
}
```

And the output: `Size of list: 10`

Comment: This work because `TParameter` inherits QObject and you stick to `this` in the creator